# Do we want Hats?

Tags: discussion

Is it too late to dredge-up the necessary interest in WinterBash?

From other meta-sites, I think we've just got one day to show some interest!

Comment: Summer starts here in about 3 hours! Hard to get enthused about winter.

Comment: Hm. It is a bit Northern-Hemisphere-specific. If it helps, [the picure I saw](http://meta.music.stackexchange.com/questions/610/winterbash-2013) looked a lot less "winter-themed" than previous years.

Comment: Hm. Did it work?

Comment: Well, I submitted the form. Not sure if it's too late. We'll see. :-P (It's certainly possible that @gnibbler submitted ahead of me, though.)

Comment: Apparently it's not too late. I just got an email from the admin team fishing for us stragglers

Answer (score 9):

### Yes! I want hats during WinterBash!

Answer (score 1):

### No! I do not want hats on Programming Puzzles & Code-Golf SE.